# Selenium Grid with Chrome 113 against MacOS throws exception (cannot determine loading status)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am using Selenium Grid (selenium-server-standalone.3.14.0) with chromedriver 113.0.5672.63 to run Selenium tests against MacOS (10.15 Catalina) using NUnit.

Some tests passed successfully, but some random tests sometimes failed with error on IWebElement.Click():

```
unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from no such window
  (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.92).

Exception Stack Trace:    
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
```

Any ideas, how to fix it?

I think, it may be related to some changes in Chrome 113 - for example, TestComplete also has issues with Chrome 113: *https://community.smartbear.com/t5/TestComplete-Questions/TestComplete-issues-with-Chrome-113/td-p/249733*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **workaround**, I am using JavaSctipt click on element

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I am having the exact same issue running cucumber tests for a Rails app with selenium-webdriver to drive Chrome 113 on OSX. The error also only shows when we run more than one test against the same session.

In my case at least, if I catch and ignore the error, the test will run fine. Not a great solution, but it works as a hacky workaround until something better comes up.

See @Unixmonkey's answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/76240293/399281

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing the same thing with Rails (7.0.4.3), Capybara (3.39.0), & Selenium-webdriver (4.9.1), all newest releases right now.

Tests that passed just fine a few days to weeks ago without any changes (but perhaps CircleCI shipped an updated `chromedriver` or `geckodriver`) have started failing randomly, but we have so many system tests, it was getting rare to have a passing suite.

It appears that the problem only occurs on the initial `visit` to a URL, so I was able to catch and retry the `visit` call with the following monkeypatch:

```rb
# Monkey patch Capybara to retry `visit` on:
#
# > Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError
# >   unknown error: cannot determine loading status
# >   from no such window
#
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/76223508/23915
module Capybara
  module DSL
    def visit(visit_uri)
      page.visit(visit_uri)
    rescue ::Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError => e
      puts e
      sleep 0.1
      page.visit(visit_uri)
    end
  end
end
```

Since putting this in, I haven't had a failed build yet, but still have a few times per build where this gets caught and prints to the console.

Hopefully it gets noticed and fixed in a newer version of either the browser drivers, or `selenium-webdriver`.